# How to scroll in a terminal using keyboard?

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I scroll in bash using only the keyboard? If it's not possible in bash, are there any other shells that support this?

Comment: This is not a feature of the shell, it's a feature of the terminal emulator. See [What is the exact difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell', a 'tty' and a 'console'?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4126) What terminal are you using?

Comment: I think this is too broad. As mentioned, scrolling is a terminal emulator feature, not a shell feature. There are *really very many* terminal emulators many of which implement scrolling in different ways, or not at all.

Comment: On that score: For a question specifically about GNOME Terminal, although the questioner initially _also_ did not specify the terminal emulator program, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/460422/ .

Answer (score 244, accepted):

In "terminal" (not a graphic emulator like `gterm`),
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd> work.

Comment: Shift+Uparrow and shift+Downarrow also work for line at a time scrolling.

Comment: for me its ctrl-shift+Uparrow

Answer (score 59):

I use the default terminal in Ubuntu 14 (bash) and to scroll by page it is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>PageUp</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>PageDown</kbd> to go up/down a whole page.

To scroll one line at a time:

- Up: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>
- Down: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd>

Comment: Bash is shell not terminal.

Answer (score 19):

This depends on your terminal emulator, not the shell you are using. I personally use [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/). From the description:

> Screen is a full-screen window manager that multiplexes a physical
>   terminal between several processes, typically interactive shells.

You can use `C-a [` to enter scrollback mode. From here, you can scroll with the keyboard and even copy and paste. The mode can be exited from by using the `Esc` key.

Answer (score 18):

**Keyboard:** Apple/Mac

**Terminal/Emu:** OSX Terminal

**Shell:** bash

```
fn + up_arrow: page up
fn + down_arrow: page down
cmd + up_arrow: line up
cmd + down_arrow: line down
```

Comment: This adds nothing, appears to be mac specific (which would not be a bad thing if properly marked as such), and does not apply to bash but to the terminal emulator (which would be useful if we knew what it was).

Answer (score 7):

On FreeBSD, you can use <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> to toggle screen scrolling mode.  Press it once, then use Up/Down, PgUp/PgDown, Home/End to scroll.  Press it again to jump back down and resume typing.

Comment: damn it, <key>Scroll Lock</key> just lost its function in gnome-terminal.

Answer (score 6):

In most terminals that I known you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>DownDown</kbd> for scrolling. Note that some terminals don't support scrolling, or use a very limited history buffer. In the latter case, you may want to increase the limit, if it is configurable.

As an alternative, use a pager; for example, `less`.

Answer (score 2):

**Linux on Apple / Mac Keyboard (at least on MacBook Pro)**

- **Page-up:**  *shift+fn+UpArrow*
- **Page-down:**  *shift+fn+DownArrow*
- **Line-up:**  *shift+control+UpArrow*
- **Line-down:**  *shift+control+DownArrow*
- **Home:**  *shift+fn+LeftArrow*
- **End:**  *shift+fn+RightArrow*

Answer (score 2):

I access a container via an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS terminal, from a Windows machine.
I needed to use space (when inside a bash session on a Docker container running  Linux Ubuntu).

Comment: Please consider adding some more information on the virtual environment of your container (such as OS type/version, bash version etc.) so that readers may better assess the applicability of your answer to their specific situation.

Comment: What ... pressing space?

Answer (score 1):

If you use VirtureBoxVM on Mac OS, press SHIFT + fn + up_arrow ( or down_arrow) to roll.

Answer (score 1):

There is an another way to show everything in terminal organized write to the last to any command " | less " and by clicking SPACE BUTTON you can scroll down an up.

#### Examples

- `ps aux`
- `ps aux | less`
- `ps fax`
- `ps fax | less`

Answer (score 1):

I don't have <kbd>PgUp</kbd> so I use <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>UpArrow</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Its also depend on your keyboard PageUp/Down and arrow keys layout.
Here is my keyboard layout and I am using Ubuntu.

[image: Keyboard]

Answered by @Guzman is working for me.

```
Page-up: shift+fn+UpArrow
Page-down: shift+fn+DownArrow
Line-up: shift+control+UpArrow
Line-down: shift+control+DownArrow
Home: shift+fn+LeftArrow
End: shift+fn+RightArrow
```